# Meaning of the metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I took a relativity class as an undergraduate but lost contact with the theory many years ago. Recently I took some old notes to revisit some concepts. I am a layman in the subject, so I apologize in advance for the basic question but I have never seen any satisfactoric explanantion on the matter.

The metric tensor $g$ tells you how spacetime curves and, consequently, how one measures distances. In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ the norm $\|x\|$ has the natural interpretation of the lenght of the vector $x$ or the distance between the point $x$ and the origin. In relativity, we talk about four dimensional vectors ${\bf{x}}=(ct,x,y,z)$. Whats does $g({\bf{x}}, {\bf{x}})=(ct)^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$ means? What does it measure? In other worlds, why is the metric tensor defined as:
\begin{equation}
g=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & -1& 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
in flat spacetime?

Comment: "Why?" is a difficult question in physics because it's likely to be a never-ending tower of why's. The most relevant answer is that we find from experiments and observations that if we define the metric $g$ to be the one above, then one can accurately predict the outcomes of said experiments.

Comment: @Prahar, I know the "why" question is difficult, but I thought there was something more about it. I remember when the professor deduced the Lorentz transformation in class. If one person, in some reference frame, send a light signal at time $t=0$, in time $t>0$ this light signal would have illuminated a whole sphere $(ct)^{2}-x^2-y^2-z^2 = 0$. This is precisely $g({\bf{x}},{\bf{x}}) = 0$. What's inside of the sphere is what you can see because nothing travels faster than $c$. I thought the metric tensor could be deduced or given a meaning out of some toy model like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It measures the "wristwatch time" $\tau$ between two events. This is the time read on a wristwatch that passes through both events at constant velocity. This is because $\tau$  is invariant and $dx=dy=dz=0$ in that frame so $d\tau=cdt$. (You made a little error in your metric. The space intervals should all have the same sign.) But there is a lot more to say about the metric. It's subtle. Check out [Exploring Black Holes](https://www.eftaylor.com/exploringblackholes/) by Taylor and Wheel. The entire book is about the metric. More advanced books tend to gloss over the physical meaning of the metric. For example, that an object moving in a gravitational field takes the path of maximal aging.  If there is no gravity then this path is a straight line. The metric also allows you to compare space and time intervals in different reference frames such as [stationary and rotating](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148439/can-a-ultracentrifuge-be-used-to-test-general-relativity) or far away from a massive object and close to that object.

Comment: Jelly, thanks for your answer. I don't think I fully understand, however. What exactly do you mean by "passes through both events"? What I mean is: the "norm" $g({\bf{x}},{\bf{x}}) = (ct)^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}-z^{2}$ should be a property of the vector ${\bf{x}}$ (or its coordinates) alone, right? How come it tells something about two events? Do you mean that one event ocurred at the origin?

Comment: @IamWill $g(x,x)$ is the dot product in spacetime. It's square root gives the distance, in spacetime, between two events where x is the vector connecting them.

Comment: @IamWill the spacetime "distance" between events connected by a light ray is 0.